# Need to link two button texts to eachother?

Tags: c#

I have two table layout panels with 26 buttons each. I need to link the two button texts to each other. I have two Lists containing one language for one set of buttons and another language for another set of buttons. I tried to link the two lists together in order to set their translations but it didnt work. So for example if you click on one button the text "Hello" will show and another button "Salut". If its a match they must either disappear.

```
Random random = new Random();

List<string> EngBasicPhrases = new List<string>()
{
    "Hello", "How are you?", "Hot",  "Thank you", "Welcome",
    "Let's go", "My name is...", "Cold", "Good luck",
    "Congratulations", "Bless you","I forgot","Sorry","I'm fine",
    "It's no problem","Don't worry","Here it is","What?","Of course",
    "Boy","Girl","Man","Woman","Friend","Almost","Late"

};

List<string> FrBasicPhrases = new List<string>()
{
    "Salut","Ca va?","Chaud", "Merci", "Bienvenu", "Allons-y","Je m'appelle","Du froid",
    "Bonne chance","Felicitations","A vos souhaits","J'ai oublie","Desole","Je vais bien",
    "Ce n'est pas grave","Ne t'en fais pas","Voila","Comment?","Bien sur","Un garcon","Une fille",
    "Un home","Une femme","Un ami","Presque","En retard"
};

Button firstClicked, secondClicked;

public Game()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AssignWordsToSquares();
    EngBasicPhrases.AddRange(FrBasicPhrases);

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstClicked != null && secondClicked != null)
        return;

    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton == null)
        return;

    if (clickedButton.ForeColor == Color.Black)
        return;

    if(firstClicked == null)
    {
        firstClicked = clickedButton;
        firstClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        return;
    }

    secondClicked = clickedButton;
    secondClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;

    CheckForWinner1();

    if (firstClicked.Text == secondClicked.Text)
    {
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }
    else
        timer1.Start();
}

private void CheckForWinner1()
{
    Button button1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        button1 = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] as Button;

        if (button1 != null && button1.ForeColor == button1.BackColor)
            return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations!");
}

private void Button_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstClicked != null && secondClicked != null)
        return;

    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton == null)
        return;

    if (clickedButton.ForeColor == Color.Black)
        return;

    if (firstClicked == null)
    {
        firstClicked = clickedButton;
        firstClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        return;
    }

    secondClicked = clickedButton;
    secondClicked.ForeColor = Color.Black;

    CheckForWinner2();

    if (firstClicked.Text == secondClicked.Text)
    {
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }
    else
        timer1.Start();
}


private void CheckForWinner2()
{
    Button button2;


    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        button2 = tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[i] as Button;

        if (button2 != null && button2.ForeColor == button2.BackColor)
            return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations!");
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    firstClicked.ForeColor = firstClicked.BackColor;
    secondClicked.ForeColor = secondClicked.BackColor;

    firstClicked = null;
    secondClicked = null;


}

private void AssignWordsToSquares()
{
    Button button1 = button2;

    int randomNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is Button)
            button1 = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
        else
            continue;

        randomNumber = random.Next(0, EngBasicPhrases.Count);
        button1.Text = EngBasicPhrases[randomNumber];

        EngBasicPhrases.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[i] is Button)
            button2 = (Button)tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[i];
        else
            continue;

        randomNumber = random.Next(0, FrBasicPhrases.Count);
        button2.Text = FrBasicPhrases[randomNumber];

        FrBasicPhrases.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Dictionary<int, string>` may be enough. Same key, same string in two different languages. You could use the Buttons' Tag property to assign the dictionary Key. Compare the selected Button's Tag in the first set to the Tag of the Button in the other language set.

Comment: I'm still confused about the intent use case. Is this a word game where the user is supposed to click buttons with matched meaning? Or, is this supposed to simply replace words on buttons based on my language preference selection?

Comment: It's a memory game with different languages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you seem to have two lists to use for ordinal comparison. So, you don't really need to match the words, but the indexes of both lists. That makes sense. But, then it all gets confusing.

Your code does the following right now:

- Create a list of English phrases
- Create a list of French phrases
- Start form
- loop through English panel buttons

  - add a random English phrase to a button in control panel
  - remove phrase from English list
- loop through French panel buttons

  - add a random French phrase to a button in control panel
  - remove phrase from French list
- Add all remaining French phrases to the list of remaining English phrases (this step seems unnecessary either way)

So now you have your form loaded. If you have less buttons in your panels than you have words in your list, you might have ended up with words in either panel that cannot be matched.

Now you run into this:

```cs
private void Button_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
[...]
    if (firstClicked.Text == secondClicked.Text)
    {
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }
[...]
```

this is the only place I see an attempt to compare the values of the button. But, by this point there is no way they'll ever match. "Hello" is a string that will never match "Salut" for example. And, since the lists are no longer intact, they can't be used to help match them. Other wise you could just find phrases in their respective lists and check if indexes match.

To allow this, you need to change how you add the button text in your code. Instead of using the list directly create an array from your list. Something like this:

```cs
    string[] phrases= EngBasicPhrases.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is Button)
            button1 = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
        else
            continue;

        randomNumber = random.Next(0, phrases.Count - 1);
        button1.Text = phrases[randomNumber];

        phrases.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
    }

    phrases= FrBasicPhrases.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[i] is Button)
            button2 = (Button)tableLayoutPanel2.Controls[i];
        else
            continue;

        randomNumber = random.Next(0, phrases.Count);
        button2.Text = phrases[randomNumber];

        phrases.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
    }
```

There are some other problems in how you're working with the variables and attempting to use colors to determine state of the button, or infer meaning. But, I'll let you work through those. I recommend using breakpoints and stepping through the code to see the state of your variables and intercept events.

Comment: How are you comparing the 2 words now?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Dictionary. I would link values like this:

```
button1.Text == dict[button2.Text]
```